# merging PDFs with Ghostscipt ignoring outline and using pdfmark instead

Tags: merge, ghostscript, tableofcontents

I am using a Batch script to merge different PDFs in one complete file.

```
 %gsc% -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dEPSFitPage -o  %dsk%%zus%%ext% %mfd% %pth%tmp\pdfmarks

 %dsk%%zus%%ext%: Path and name of final (complete) document

 %mfd%: Path and name of docs to be merged (c:\test\1.pdf c:\test\2.pdf ...)

 %pth%tmp = path to the pdfmarks file
```

Additionally, I am creating a pdfmark document inside the script which gs uses to create the bookmarks. But unfortunately, some of the docs I am merging, have already their own bookmarks and I did not yet find a solution how to ignore those. GS should only use the bookmarks inside the pdfmarks file.

How can this be done?

Comment: If you have two questions, you should ask two questions and not append it to the original one.

Comment: Sorry, it just came to my mind at the end of typing. As it was of minor importance, I've added it. I wasn't aware, that this is a nogo hre in the forum. Please accept my sincere apologies. I took it our of the original post. Is there any chance you can help me with my issue(s)?

Comment: @Kami Kaze: I just tried to post a second question. But I am only allowed to post once every 90 minutes...

Comment: No problem, it is just that the question (with a good title) and the answers are a unit. And by asking another question you distract from the intended content proposed by the title. Yeah the limitations are a bit of a hassle, but they will be gone soon if you write good content.

Comment: I'll try my best :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly; you are not 'merging' PDF files when you use Ghotscript's pdfwrite device. The process is described in detail [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm#Overview)

The important point is that the way the input file(s) are constructed has no bearing on the way the output file is constructed. If any other software you use relies on the file being constructed in a particular fashion it may not work on the output PDF file.

The `-dEPSFitPage` switch **only** has any effect when the input is an EPS file. If you want to 'fit' PostScript or PDF files then you need to use `-dPDFFitPage`, `-dPSFitPage` or just `-dFitPage`. However, all of these rely on you first selecting a media size, and then preventing it being altered by setting `-dFIXEDMEDIA`. For EPS files you would more normally use `-dEPSCrop` which sets the media size to the EPS declared BoundingBox.

You can prevent the PDF interpreter reading the Outlines tree (which you are calling Bookmarks) and then creating a pdfmark from it to pass to the pdfwrite device by using the `-dNO_PDFMARK_OUTLINES` switch which oddly isn't documented, presumably an oversight.

Comment: Thanks KenS for your tip: the magic words have been `-dNO_PDFMARK_OUTLINES` It works for the bookmarks pretty well, but is ignoring Preferences such as title, author, etc.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'Preferences', those are entries in the Document Info dict. They are (I think) preserved by the PDF interpreter by creating DOCINFO pdfmarks from the. I haven't actually checked this though. I don't believe that -dNO_PDFMARK_OUTLINES should affect this in any way.

Comment: With "preferences" I mean the part where I can see Author and Title. My pdfmark looks as follows:
`[ /Title (Docs from Company Name)
[ /Author (Company Name)
[ /Subject (Docs for calibration)
[ /Creator (PPT - Paul's PDF Tool) `

But in the "preferences" it still shows as title the Indesign Filename from which the first PDF in the "merge" was originally generated and the Username in our active directory who did it... It does not overwrite it with those values above. Perhaps I need to search if there is an option to kill all those entries from the PDF... Need to check tomorrow.

Comment: You're going to need to show me a complete pdfmark (which that isn't, or at least, not a single valid pdfmark) and a command line so I can see how you are using it. Without that, I can't help. Best bet; edit your question and add that.